# Пробел в конце кода после создания класса в IntelliJ IDEA, как убрать?)

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

Возможно это глупо, но вот этот пробел мне уже которые сутки при создании класса не дает спать, пересмотрел настройки 6 раз.Как сделать чтоб не появлялся?

[image: скриншот]

его конечно можно удалить после создания, но хочется что бы оно вообще не появлялось

Comment: А еще бесит, что автосеттер добавляет лишний \n внутри тела метода

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/file-and-code-templates.html

Comment: Эээ.. Ну вопрос-то зачем минусовать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Во-первых, это перевод строки, а не пробел, а во-вторых, оставь его в покое, иначе в git'е ещё хуже будет. Да и вообще, завершать файл переводом строки уже стало стандартом.

[image: Скриншот из SourseTree]